# How can I convert a file and save it on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to save a file from a request. How can I change the format of an image and how can I rename them?

Can anyone show me code to rename and convert the format of an image to PNG and save them on server?

Answer (score 0):

How do you retrieve the file and what format is the file in?

You might be able to load it into a [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) and then save it using the Bitmap.Save(String, ImageFormat) method. There you can specify the name of the file as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very easy:

```
// Load the image.
    System.Drawing.Image image1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\test.bmp");

    // Save the image in JPEG format.
    image1.Save(@"C:\test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    // Save the image in GIF format.
    image1.Save(@"C:\test.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

    // Save the image in PNG format.
    image1.Save(@"C:\test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```